# HTML Parsing using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I need to parse a webpage and extract some values from it. So I created a python parser as follow:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Data     :", data

f=open("result.html","r")
s=f.read()
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(s)
```

The program reads html file and prints the data from it.

I passed following result.html, here parser works fine

```
<tr class='trmenu1'>
<td>Marks Obtained: </td><td colspan=1>75.67 Out of 100</td>
</tr>
<tr class='trmenu1'>
<td>GATE Score: </td><td colspan=1>911</td>
</tr>
<tr class='trmenu1'>
<td>All India Rank: </td><td colspan=1>34</td>
</tr>
```

After passing the above html the output is:

> Data     :
>
> Data     : Marks Obtained:
>   Data     : 75.67 Out of 100  Data     :
>
> Data     :
>
> Data     :
>
> Data     : GATE Score:
>   Data     : 911
>   Data     :
>
> Data     :
>
> Data     :
>
> Data     : All India Rank:
>   Data     : 34

But the parser is supposed to read a larger file and the code mentioned above is small part of that large file. The file is too large to paste here. So I uploaded it at following link: http://www.mediafire.com/?dsgr1gdjvs59c7c
When passed the larger file, parser doesn't read all the entries leaving some blank entries in output.
Part of output is shown below:

> Data     : Syllabi
>
> Data     :
>
> Data     : GATE Score
>
> Data     :
>
> Data     : GATE Results
>
> Data     :

Observe the blank entry in the line below Gate Score which was 911 in previous output.

The parser works fine with small file but not with the large file
Why is this happening? I am using Python 2.7

Comment: try to use `BeautifulSoup.py` script. It does the job very well for parsing HTML file.

Comment: @Coder why is LibXml better than BeautifulSoup? Does it handle poorly constructed HTML? What does it do better?

Comment: I have used *BeautifulSoup* and it's great to use, solid component. @Coder you might want to update your link as it had `]` included in the link

Comment: @Josh Smeaton: `lxml` is lighting fast and more updated. Even `BeautifulSoup4` recommends you to install `lxml` and will use it if available.

Comment: 1) I've used both BeautifulSoup and Lxml and found that lxml is faster than BeautifulSoup. 2) Lxml too handles broken html.

Comment: @Coder and fastreload good to know thanks for the info

Comment: Updated link: [Lxml](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My preferred solution for parsing HTML or XML is `lxml` and `xpath`.

A quick and dirty example of how you might use `xpath`:

```
from lxml import etree
data = open('result.html','r').read()
doc = etree.HTML(data)

for tr in doc.xpath('//table/tr[@class="trmenu1"]'):
  print tr.xpath('./td/text()')
```

Yields:

```
['Registration Number: ', ' CS 2047103']
['Name of the Candidate: ', 'PATIL SANTOSH KUMARRAO        ']
['Examination Paper: ', 'CS - Computer Science and Information Technology']
['Marks Obtained: ', '75.67 Out of 100']
['GATE Score: ', '911']
['All India Rank: ', '34']
['No of Candidates Appeared in CS: ', '156780']
['Qualifying Marks for CS: ', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t']
['General', 'OBC ', '(Non-Creamy)', 'SC / ST / PD ']
['31.54', '28.39', '21.03 ']
```

This code creates an `ElementTree` out of the HTML data. Using `xpath`, it selects all `<tr>` elements where there is an attribute of `class="trmenu1"`. Then for each `<tr>` it selects and prints the text of any `<td>` children.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @NoémienKocher I provided a solution to the OP's problem and the OP was happy with it, over 4 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully at the html page on mediafire you'll notice that you have two text blocks that contain "GATE Score"

```
 line 162: <tr><td class='qlink4' background='webimages/blkbuttona3.jpg' onMouseOut="background='webimages/blkbuttona3.jpg'" onMouseOver="background='webimages/blkbuttonb3.jpg'">&nbsp;<a class="dark2" href="gscore.php" title="GATE Score">GATE Score</a></td></tr>

 line 192: <tr class='trmenu1'><td>GATE Score: </td><td colspan=1>911</td></tr>
```

The problem you are having is probably due to an error in the full html page you are trying to parse, that's why you can only see one "GATE Score" occurrence.

As you were suggested in the comments, use BeautifulSoup that is more tolerant of malformed html.